# Selenium remote webdriver timeouts after 60 secs, c# vs2015

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, remotewebdriver

I am facing an issue with selenium web driver c#.  I am running a test via chrome on my local machine and launching chrome driver with `driver = new Chrome Driver()`. For one of the pages, the page takes more than 60 secs to load and fetch all elements and I am shown every time this message.

Any thoughts? Also I am using visual studio 2015 with Nunit.

Answer (score 0):

There is an overload to specify a command timeout (which defaults to 60), but you'll have to also pass in a `ChromeOptions`:

https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Chrome_ChromeDriver__ctor_3.htm

For example:

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(), new ChromeOptions(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I am not using chrome driver .exe for launching chrome driver as I had to then update chromedriver .exe later. Is there any other way to solve this timeout issue while I'm instantiating chrome browser via 'new ChromeDriver()'.

Comment: I've updated the link to use a different overload instead of string path. `IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(), new ChromeOptions(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));`

Comment: thanks a lot Lucas for your reply. It worked for me.